# How to interpret statistical insignificance of explanatory variables that may be indirectly affecting Y?

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, multicollinearity, logit, interpretation

I have modeled Y (binary variable) on a set of explanatory variables, X, using logistic regression. A number of x's, say 10 of them, are found to be significantly affecting Y (based on LR test). Then I model another binary variable Z, on X and Y. Y is found to be significantly affecting Z, but almost none of the x's are. I thought it should be because of multicollinearity (as Y is already in the model, x's are not needed), so I removed Y and still x's coefficients are not statistically significant. How can I interpret this?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer the question as significance of variables vary a lot depending on what other variables you include and if you have misspecified your model. 
I don't know how much variance of Y is explained by x. x just being significant doesn't mean that you don't have an omitted variable bias. 
Meaning, that if x only explains a very small part of the variance in Y and you are omitting variables and your model is misspecified, then your significance doesn't mean much (as the model is misspecified). 
So if x doesn't explain much variance in y,  when you then later try to explain Z by x instead of Y, then you won't get the results you expect.

Remember that omitting variables or including variables in the model that have multicollinearity will lead to model misspecification and you significance or coefficients won't match the 'true model'.

Additionally: you could test for multicollinearity with a VIF test.